# Constant error in my PHP code. Always geting "wrong password" message

Tags: php, html, webforms

There is an issue with the code somewhere, but don't know where.
It's has been copied from chat gpt.
thats my code :

```
<?php


session_start();

include 'config.php'; // Zaimportuj plik z połączeniem do bazy danych

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    // Połącz z bazą danych
    
    
    if (!$conn) {
        die("Błąd połączenia z bazą danych: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    // Pobierz dane z formularza
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["username"]);
    $password = $_POST["password"];

    // Znajdź użytkownika w bazie danych
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

        // Sprawdź hasło
        if (password_verify($password, $row["password"])) {
            $_SESSION["user_id"] = $row["id"];
            $_SESSION["username"] = $row["username"];
            header("Location: www.wp.pl"); // Przekierowanie na stronę główną po zalogowaniu
        } else {
            echo "Nieprawidłowe hasło.";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Użytkownik o podanej nazwie nie istnieje.";
    }

    // Zamknij połączenie z bazą danych
    mysqli_close($conn);
}
?>
```

Is there something wrong with it ?

I have tried changing the password couple of times, but it doesn't make any difference.
Any ideas ? What can I do to sort it ?

Comment: _"Is there something wrong with it ?"_ - there is of course _everything_ wrong with the attempt to get proper code for a login system, from ChatGPT.

Comment: You have only shown us the part where you try to _verify_ the login credentials; we have not seen yet, how they got stored into the database to begin with. The verification code expects the password in the database to be hashed - whether you actually did that, we can't tell right now.

Comment: Isn't ChatGPT temp banned? This question is a prime example of why: This code is dangerous and vulnerable to SQL Injection.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are getting the wrong password message, we can assume that the DB connection is correct and the problem is within this part:

```php
if (password_verify($password, $row["password"])) {
    $_SESSION["user_id"] = $row["id"];
    $_SESSION["username"] = $row["username"];
    header("Location: www.wp.pl"); // Przekierowanie na stronę główną po zalogowaniu
} else {
    echo "Nieprawidłowe hasło.";
}
```

The `password_verify` function, as we can see from [the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php): Verifies that a password matches a hash.
So, you should check how you store the password in the DB. The `$row["password"]` should be a valid hash that you get by passing the password to the `password_hash` function. You can check [how this works here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php).

This seems to be the part that fails, so double check your stored password.